# I'm trying to connect my rds db instance using aws rds proxy and i'm getting this error. (using password No)

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-rds

> 2022-05-10T11:32:37.714Z [INFO] [proxyEndpoint=default]
> [clientConnection=2983104718] Proxy authentication with IAM
> authentication failed for user "admin" with TLS on. Reason: The IAM
> user "arn:aws:iam::671748316024:root" isn't authorized to perform
> action rds-db:connect on this proxy resource. Refer to
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html
> on how to authorize the user

I'm using the same security group for my lambda function, RDS DB and RDS proxy.
I have also added the vpc to proxy inbound.

[this is the image of all policies that are attached to the role I'm using for the lambda function.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0zEk.png)

[rds-connect policy as mentions in error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wexs2.png)